# Whoops, looks like something went wrong in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have application developed in Laravel 5.8.

And I get this message `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

If the form content is just : `input` and `image`,then no problem.
If the form content has `input`, `image` and `textarea`, then I get this message 
`Whoops, looks like something went wrong`

I try to set `APP_DEBUG = True` and clear cache, but the errors are still not visible.
And i don't have any element in LOG.

Anyone help me, because this project is in production.

[image]

Comment: also try to run php artisan config:cache

Comment: Show the section where is actually error

Comment: i guess my answer just fixing how to use old_value on textarea, but i didnt see any wrong in html, based on image you uploaded, idk the rest of it or maybe when you post the form, maybe its on controller

Comment: @NaveedAli     i was run that Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
   Artisan::call('config:clear');
   Artisan::call('config:cache');
   Artisan::call('view:clear'); 
   return "Cleared!";
});  But nothing changed

Comment: @AlzafanChristian   The request didnt arrive to controller.

Comment: then put the pieces here, like "when i post my form i got error", attach the controller-code where the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put old_value in `<textarea>` should be `<textarea name="description" etc.>{{old('description')}}</textarea>` not using `value="{{old('description')}}"`

Comment: I want to thank you, but the value doesn't the exact error

Comment: yeah, i asked you to verify where the process goes error, current answer just suggesting the old_value usage on <textarea>